# Disallow ambiguous dates

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, datetime

`DateTime.Parse(myString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` gladly parses the following **unambiguous** dates (assuming a fixed local time zone):

```
2015-12-31T12:15:00
2015-12-31T12:15:00Z
2015-12-31T12:15:00+01:00
2015-12-31T12:15
2015-12-31
2015-12-31 12:15:00
2015-12-31 12:15:00Z
2015-12-31 12:15:00+01:00
2015-12-31 12:15
```

This is great. I love all the flexibility. Unfortunately, it also parses the following **ambiguous** date:

```
4.3.2015   // The user intent could be March or April.
```

I know that I can use ParseExact, but then I'd have to submit a large list of all the unambiguous date formats that could possibly be submitted to my application.

Can I somehow just disallow ambiguous date formats **without having to specify each unambiguous format to ParseExact**? Something like `DateTime.Parse(myString, IsoCulture)`?

Comment: Sidestepping the issue, but if you are expecting direct user input of the dates, why not echo the input back to them so they know how the program is interpreting their input.

Comment: I think that would be better to put all the possible cases in there. It will be more stable and error free logic

Comment: @Oliver: This is for a web API which can be accessed from different programming languages. Most of them are able to output *some kind* of ISO-compatible date easily, so I'd like to accept all of them. On the other hand, I'd like to reject ambiguous dates to help prevent programming errors on the client side.

Comment: If this is for an API, could you require the application to send you the date in a specific format (such as yyyymmdd), or to send you an indication of what format the string is in?

Comment: The parsing use the current culture ([look at the last sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182189.aspx)), the dot and dash are for specific formats, for a specific order.

Comment: Presumably if the user has entered `4.3.2015` the intent is that they entered it using the current culture format, so you could just change to use `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`

Comment: Having said that the user should not be allowed to enter `4.3.2015` use a DateTimePicker control and retrieve the `Value` property

Comment: @Blackwood: Yes, that might be what I will do, if there is no easy answer to my question. I'd just like to be liberal in what I accept (as long as it's unambiguous, hence my question).

Comment: I understand the idea of being liberal in what you accept, but in this case, I'm not sure it helps users of your API. Before sending a date to you, they would have to do the check to see if it could be ambiguous and reformat it if that is the case. It would be easier for them to just always reformat the date to be whatever format you specify.

Comment: I think the best you can do is provide immediate feedback of the date entered in a local unambiguous format. If the user enters d-m-y and they were instructed to enter m-d-y there isn't much else you can do other than replace the user. :)

Comment: Apparently, your requirements go against the underlying intention of the over-understanding DateTime type. I guess that this is the reason for having Parse and ParseExact (what does not happen with any other type); that is: Parse delivers the behavior under the most likely conditions (as over-understanding as possible); and ParseExact takes care of particularly-strict situations. Why not accepting the information from a user relying on a slightly different format as a general rule? The more adaptable, the better isn't it? After doing some tests, I think that your goal cannot be accomplished.

Comment: @Blackwood: Ah, I see the misunderstanding here: I would like to ban ambiguous *formats*, not ambiguous dates. You are right that accepting `1.1.2015` but banning `3.4.2015` would be confusing. I basically only want to accept ISO, in it's various varieties (with/without space, with/without `T`, with/without time zone, ...)

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can do this by providing one single format option.

Here is my starter for ten which will at least make sure the date portion is in the correct format:

```
Public Function ParseUnAmbiguousDate(s As String, ByRef aDateTime As DateTime) As Boolean

    'keep a track of how long the date portion is
    Dim dateLength As Integer = 0
    'there are only two valid date formats in ISO terms yyyy-MM-dd or yyyyMMdd so try these first

    'is it too short?
    If s.Length < 8 Then Return False
    'try the yyyyMMdd format
    If DateTime.TryParseExact(s.Substring(0, 8), "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, aDateTime) Then
        dateLength = 8
    End If

    'try the yyyy-MM-dd format if the first option failed
    If dateLength = 0 Then
        'is it too short for this format?
        If s.Length < 12 Then Return False

        If DateTime.TryParseExact(s.Substring(0, 10), "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, aDateTime) Then
            dateLength = 10
        End If
    End If

    'if we get here then check we have found a format
    If dateLength = 0 Then Return False

    'now substitue our date for a known one to try and parse the time
    Dim timePortion As Date
    If DateTime.TryParse("2000-01-01" & s.Substring(dateLength), timePortion) Then
        aDateTime = New DateTime(aDateTime.Year, aDateTime.Month, aDateTime.Day, timePortion.Hour, timePortion.Minute, timePortion.Second, timePortion.Kind)
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If

End Function
```

Answer (score -3):

It can be done with this extension:

```
using System;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace UnitTestProject1
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestCase("2015-12-31", true)]
        [TestCase("2015-01-01", true)]
        [TestCase("2015-12-31 12:15:00+01:00", true)]
        [TestCase("4.3.2015", false)]
        [TestCase("4.13.2015", true)]
        [TestCase("13.13.2015", false, ExpectedException = typeof(FormatException))]
        public void TestMethod1(string input, bool expected)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, input.IsDateNotAmbigous());
        }
    }

    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static bool IsDateNotAmbigous(this string stringDateTime)
        {
            DateTime parsed = DateTime.Parse(stringDateTime);
            return parsed.Day == parsed.Month || parsed.Day>12;
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I think I'll have to agree with the public on this one, that without having knowledge of the incoming strings culture, it is not an easily solvable problem. Even if we did iterate through all the available cultures like so:

```
    public static bool IsDateNotAmbigous(this string stringDateTime)
    {
        return CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures).AsParallel().Select(ci =>
        {
            DateTime parsed = default(DateTime);
            bool success = DateTime.TryParse(stringDateTime, ci, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out parsed);
            bool test = parsed.Day > 12 || parsed.Day == parsed.Month;
            Trace.WriteLine(String.Format("{0,12}:{1,5}:{2,5}:{3:O}", ci.Name, success, test, parsed));
            if (!success)
                return -1;
            if (test)
                return 1;
            return 0;
        }).Where(w=>w>=0).Select(s=>s==1).Aggregate((b, b1) => b || b1);
    }
```

Some test will not be passing. But perhaps it will help someone to come up with an elegant solution to this.

**Couldn't stop thinking about it**

OK, so we can't know for sure, without having some knowledge of the incoming culture, but this should get you closer:

```
#region

using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using NUnit.Framework;

#endregion

namespace UnitTestProject1
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestCase("2015-12-31", true)]
        [TestCase("2015-01-01", true)]
        [TestCase("2015-02-01", false)]
        [TestCase("2015-12-31 12:15:00+01:00", true)]
        [TestCase("4.3.2015", false)]
        [TestCase("4.13.2015", true)]
        [TestCase("13.13.2015", null, ExpectedException = typeof (InvalidOperationException))]
        public void TestMethod1(string input, bool expected)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(input.DateIsLikelyNotAmbigous(), expected);
        }
    }

    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static bool DateIsLikelyNotAmbigous(this string stringDateTime)
        {
            return CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures).AsParallel().Select(ci =>
            {
                DateTime parsed = default(DateTime);
                bool success = DateTime.TryParse(stringDateTime, ci, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out parsed);
                if (!success)
                    return -1;
                if (parsed.Day > 12 || parsed.Day == parsed.Month)
                    return 1;
                return 0;
            }).Where(w => w >= 0).Average(a => a) > 0.02;
        }
    }
}
```

Would love to hear what @hvd thinks about this.

Comment: Two different strings can return the same `DateTime` when parsed, where one string was ambiguous and the other wasn't. Looking only at the returned `DateTime` cannot give you an answer. Also, you appear to be trying to return `true` when the date is unambiguous, in a method named `IsDateAmbiguous`.

Comment: Perhaps we differ on the definition of ambiguity. From the post it looked like any date which passes Parse() but where DAY could be as well a MONTH, such date string is ambiguous. In all other cases, it is not.

Comment: "1-1-2014" is not ambiguous: it means January 1st regardless of which 1 is taken as the day. "Jan 2 2014" is also not ambiguous: there is no way that "Jan" can be the day, it will always be the month. "2014-02-01" is also not ambiguous: there is no Y-D-M format, just an Y-M-D format, so it always means Feb 1 2014.

Comment: True. Did not think about that. Updated. And good point on the valid formats. Let me noodle on this.

Comment: Technically speaking, there is nothing wrong with writing down 2015-01-02 and thinking of first of February instead of January second. In the latest attempt I make a best-guess of the user intentions. Without some rules around allowed input string formats, I can't see how this could solved.